# XSD to validate XML with different sequence elements based on parent attribute

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I've looked through the other mentions on stackoverflow and can't really see anything that fits what I am looking for.

I've generated an .xsd using JAXB, but unfortunately it's not too great, so was creating one manually when I realised there is something that doesn't really seem to match the logic of other patterns I've followed.

Rather than a lengthy description, it's probably best I show it as code. I've many xml documents, with repeated elements, these elements differ according to their parent (ItemGroup) element id. Some of these ids are repeated (as shown), some will only occur once (they end in 0 or are part of DocDetails). Additionally the elements for a particular 'id' are always the same list of elements.

In the example, those ending with 0 occur only once, ending in 1 are repeated elements (though not normally more than 2), those elements ending in 2, are repeated any number of times. This suffix numbering is artificial to make it obvious , but same fixed ItemGroup id's have either 1 or repeated elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocTree xmlns="http://wolfedgx.com/doc-list/1.0/">
    <DocDetails>
        <Title>Book Title</Title>
        <Author>Author Name</Author>
    </DocDetails>
    <ItemGroup id="10">
        <GroupCategory>52</GroupCategory>
        <Genre>Horror</Horror>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup id="11">
        <GroupHierarchy>52</GroupHierarchy>
        <Delivery>2</Delivery>
        <GroupMember>95</GroupMember>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup id="11">
        <GroupHierarchy>51</GroupHierarchy>
        <Delivery>55</Delivery>
        <GroupMember>100</GroupMember>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup id="22">
        <GroupMemberNo>95</GroupMemberNo>
        <StoreName>Denver</StoreName>
        <StoreID>92</StoreID>
        <Staff>32</Staff>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup id="52">
        <StoreREF>92</StoreREF>
        <StorePrice>1.99</StorePrice>
        <StoreLogistics>2.00</StoreLogisics>
        <ItemStored>5A</ItemStored>
        <LazyRef>Yes</LazyRef>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup id="22">
         <GroupMemberNo>95</GroupMemberNo>
        <StoreName>Alaska</StoreName>
        <StoreID>22</StoreID>
        <Staff>2</Staff>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup id="52">
        <StoreREF>22</StoreREF>
        <StorePrice>2.99</StorePrice>
        <StoreLogistics>4.00</StoreLogisics>
        <ItemStored>1A</ItemStored>
        <LazyRef>Mixed</LazyRef>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup id="22">
         <GroupMember>100</GroupMember>
        <StoreName>Washington</StoreName>
        <StoreID>34</StoreID>
        <Staff>2</Staff>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup id="52">
        <StoreREF>34</StoreREF>
        <StorePrice>2.99</StorePrice>
        <StoreLogistics>4.00</StoreLogisics>
        <ItemStored>1A</ItemStored>
        <LazyRef>Mixed</LazyRef>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup id="90">
        <Misc>No additional information</Misc>
    </ItemGroup>
 </DocTree>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to validate these elements based on their ItemGroup id number. I can't use xsd 1.1 because I have to use JAXB to process the data. In addition, the XML is fixed, so I cannot restructure it. You will notice that the data actually is linked to one another, validating that would be great, but it's not absolutely necessary, presently it would be good just to validate the elements based on ItemGroups.

Below is an addition to this question, but does not answer it. It's a proposed xsd workaround, but avoids validating based on InfoGroup id and should allow for many/0 occurrances of each attribute.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://wolfedgx.com/doc-list/1.0/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="DocTree" type="ns:DocTree" xmlns:ns="http://wolfedgx.com/doc-list/1.0/"/>
<xs:complexType name="DocDetails">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Title" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Author" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="InfoGroup">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="GroupCategory" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Genre" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="GroupHierarchy" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="Delivery" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="GroupMember" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="GroupMemberNo" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="StoreName" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="StoreID" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="Staff" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="StoreREF" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:float" name="StorePrice" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:float" name="StoreLogistics" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ItemStored" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="LazyRef" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Misc" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="id"/>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

A classic example of co-occurrence constraints. This needs XSD 1.1.

JAXB is really only suitable for XML with a highly regular and stable structure. Consider using XSLT to transform the XML to something else before processing it with JAXB.

Comment: Thanks @michael-kay, I read through your other posts as well, very helpful. I updated this question with what is a proposed workaround, but it definitely strays from validation (so I don't feel it fits an 'answer'). If at all possible I will still use xlst as you suggested, then validate. Please let me know what you think of the proposed workaround.